# Google Analytics with already published app on Google play

Tags: android, google-analytics

Can Somebody guide me that is it possible to integrate Google Analytics with already published Android apps on Google play?
Because I have tried creating an account on Google analytics and then I connected Google developer account with it. At Google analytics I

1. created an admin account.

   2. created a property.
   3. created a user view.
   4. integrate it with one of my already published app.

But even after 24 hours I can see nothing on Google analytics.
So Is it really the only way to write trackers in code before launching it? But as I got to some point by connecting app to analytics I think there might be a way to do so with already published apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with iOS app, I missed in first version and then later added. It works properly. Just check time graph, there it will display always a day you can change date and can check.

Comment: Hey @kprof can you explain me bit more? How you added it later? same like me? without code ?

Comment: - There is no way you can add into already publish app an analytics engine, but you can integrate into next version since you are using Android market your app will get publish immediately. There are lot of other vendors as marketing tools, "AppAnalyzer" which can track your app which country or rank you can track. "http://applyzer.com"

Answer (score 0):

To enable Analytics in your app you need to link the app to Google Play Services and initialize Google Analytics following the developer guide:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#setup-overview

Unfortunately, this can not be done after you have shipped your app. It requires app update.

Comment: Thanks djabi. I understood this. yes I hav to add it in next update.